# Use LibGdx libraries with existing android project?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a project that I have been working on which is a standard android application that does not include any other external libraries at this time. I am now looking at making a game at the end of the app(its a quiz so after the questions I want to make a mini game).

So what I am trying to find out is can I just import the libraries that it uses and connect them to my project rather than creating a LibGDX project and importing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it comes down to is your personal preference. In answer to your question, yes you could just add in the jar files and such into your current project, however you are going to have to edit your manifest and some add in some other stuff besides jars [using this Setup](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup). In my personal opinion it would be easier to create a libgdx project using the tutorial found [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew), but in the end as I said before it all depends on what exactly you want to do.

Before deciding, ask yourself.

1. Do I want to have everything in one project, or can it be in more than one?
2. What would be better in the long run for managing my app.
3. Do I want ease now or later?

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks that helps! I just wanted to do it this way because I already have a working app which I want to game to. Didn't want all the hassle I had last time with LibGDX where my app was giving errors because of it.

Comment: @Saml92 No problem just remember if this was the answer you were looking for and you believe it answers your question remember to accept the answer. And tell me if you have any problems with whichever you choose to do.